# Toggle a value between 0 and 1 in a column, for a specific group/id, by using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset given as such in Python:

```
#Create dataset
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'cycle': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6, 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8],
        'Salary': [0, 0, 0,  0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141,123,15,85,36,58,89],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

[image]

Now, for every id/group, I wish to set value of 'Salary' as 1/0 based on certain number of cycles.

For example,

For id=1, for cycle >= 4, set 'Salary' as 1

For id=2, for cycle >= 3, set 'Salary' as 1

For id=3, for cycle >= 6, set 'Salary' as 1

The net result needs to look as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `map()`. If there are more ID's they can be added to the dictionary.

```
d = {1:4,2:3,3:6}

df.assign(Salary = df['cycle'].ge(df['id'].map(d)).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
    id  cycle  Salary  Days
0    1      1       0   123
1    1      2       0   128
2    1      3       0    66
3    1      4       1   120
4    1      5       1   141
5    1      6       1   128
6    1      7       1    66
7    1      8       1   120
8    1      9       1   141
9    2      1       0    52
10   2      2       0    96
11   2      3       1   120
12   2      4       1   141
13   2      5       1    52
14   2      6       1    96
15   3      1       0   120
16   3      2       0   141
17   3      3       0   123
18   3      4       0    15
19   3      5       0    85
20   3      6       1    36
21   3      7       1    58
22   3      8       1    89
```

Comment: Hi @rhug123. I tried using your codes as it is. But the salary column remains unchanged. Could you please let me know if there is anything missing in the codes?

Comment: try adding `df =` in front of `df.assign(...`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `loc` with conditions:

```py
conds = ((df['id'] == 1) & (df['cycle'] > 4)) | ((df['id'] == 2) & (df['cycle'] > 3)) | ((df['id'] == 3) & (df['cycle'] > 6))
df.loc[conds, 'Salary'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

after you load your data, you can make an iteration over a zip of the id, cycle and the row number , inside the loop you can match the case for the cycle, something like this:

```
for _id,_cycle,_pos in zip(data['id'],data['cycle'],range(1,len(data['id']))):
    match _id:
        case 1: 
            if _cycle>=4:
                data['Salary'][_pos]=1  
        case 2: 
            if _cycle>=3:
                data['Salary'][_pos]=1 
        case 3: 
            if _cycle>=6:
                data['Salary'][_pos]=1
```